# Show Image over a widget also half of it outside the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the example screen of I'm trying to achieve, i tried several ways, even there is lot of Stack over flow answer outside, but that's not fixing this cause .
here is the example
[image]

what my output is here

[image]

how can I achieve this, also here is my code

```
Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 145,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 300,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: sLinearColorBlue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(),
                  Positioned(
                    height: 555,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 60.0,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        child: Image.asset('assets/account.jpg'),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Did you try using the [Flutter Center](https://www.tutorialkart.com/flutter/flutter-center/) widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `Row()` within a [`Center()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) widget:

```
Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 145,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 300,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: sLinearColorBlue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(),
                    Positioned(
                      height: 555,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 60.0,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/account.jpg'),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// try align widget

Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 145,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 60.0,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/account.jpg'),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Put row inside padding. Like below.

```
Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 145,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 300,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topRight,
                      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      colors: [
                        Colors.blue,
                        Colors.red,
                      ],
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    0,
                    (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 145) - (60 * 2),
                    0,
                    0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(),
                    Positioned(
                      height: 555,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 60.0,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          child: Container(color: Colors.grey),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
 Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
      child: Container(
        width:300,
        height: 300,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
               Text('Your Data'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 90,
      width: 90,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black12,
        ),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: NetworkImage(
            'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Your Screen-> [image]